# Subprocess popen not executing the command

Tags: python-2.7

I have a set of linux commands in a file, I am trying to execute each of them one by one in python script

```
for line in file:
    p = subprocess.Popen(line,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

the above line does not execute any command as I cannot see any output.
If only the command is provided explicitly then it gets executed

```
 cmd = "date"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Just check if the line is not null and try

Comment: OK, if i provide ` back quotes, few(openssl commands) work others(date) don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.system` or `subprocess.call`.
Complete code:

```
import os
with open("/path/to/file") as file:
    command = file.readlines()
    for line in command:
         p = str(os.system(str(line)))
```

The syntax is

```
import os
os.system("path/to/executable option parameter")
```

or

`os.system("executable option paramter")`

For example,

```
os.system("ls -al /home")
```

or part of code(with `subprocess`):

```
for line in file:
    subprocess.call(line, shell=True)
```

I got this info at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

NOTE: `os.system` is deprecated but it still works

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing `shell=True`, My command was also facing same problem when I was executing this:

```py
subprocess.Popen(
  ["python3", os.path.join(script_dir, script_name)] + list(args),
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
  cwd=script_dir, 
  shell=True
)
```

but once I remove shell it worked properly.